# why my splash screen is so long

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm trying to implement a splash screen on my app. After the loading of the splash screen, I have two issues. 
If the user is connected, an activity is started. If not, an other is started.

But, with my implementation, when the user is connected, the splash screen is very long (8 or 9 sec), but I don't know why.

That is my first class which check if the user is connected, and it load some shared preferences? So maybe it's that?

```
public class AnnaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public PrefManager pref;
    private AllRequest req;
    private static final String REQUEST_TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.pref = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());
        boolean isco = pref.getIsConnect();

        if (isco) {

            Log.e("SPLASH", "IsConnected");
            Intent loginActivity = new Intent(this, NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
            startActivity(loginActivity);
            finish();

        } else {
            Log.e("SPLASH", "launch login activity");
            Intent loginActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(loginActivity);
            finish();

        }
    }
}
```

that is my splash drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    <item android:bottom="8dp"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp">
        <bitmap android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:antialias="true"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And my splach style

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_drawable</item>
</style>
```

(Edit post) The navigation drawerActivity

```
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,    Response.Listener, Response.ErrorListener{

    public TextView TextViewEmailAddress;
    public TextView TextViewLogin;
    private PrefManager pref;
    private AllRequest req;
    public RequestQueue mQueue;
    private static final String REQUEST_TAG = "LogOutActivity";

    private String address;
    private String login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)   findViewById(R.id.fab);
    //        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //            @Override
    //            public void onClick(View view) {
    //                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    //                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
    //            }
    //        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        this.TextViewEmailAddress = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.textView_drawer_mail);
        this.TextViewLogin = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.textView_drawer_login);

        this.pref = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());
        this.req = new AllRequest(getApplicationContext());
        this.mQueue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                .getRequestQueue();

        address = this.pref.getEmail();
        login = this.pref.getLogin();

        this.TextViewEmailAddress.setText(address);
        this.TextViewLogin.setText(getText(R.string.text_view_login_drawer) + " " + login);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_mon_compte) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerActivity.this, MyAccountActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_deconnection) {
            deconnexion();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void deconnexion(){
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View alertDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_logout, null);
        final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        adb.setView(alertDialogView);
        adb.setTitle(R.string.alertDialod_logout_Title);
        adb.setPositiveButton((R.string.alertDialog_logout_PositiveBtnName), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                String accessToken = pref.getAccessToken();
                req.revokeTokenRequest(REQUEST_TAG, accessToken, NavigationDrawerActivity.this, NavigationDrawerActivity.this);
                pref.logout();
                Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        adb.setNegativeButton((R.string.alertDialog_logout_NegativeBtnName), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        adb.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("errrrrrror :(", "it's not working");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Object response) {
        Log.e("pololololo","it's working :D");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to log time of methods onCreate and onResume of your activity NavigationDrawerActivity

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Comment: 1) Do not call `finish()` manually. 2) Post `NavigationDrawerActivity#onCreate()` code.

Comment: What does `PrefManager` do?

Comment: it's where I call all of my SharedPreferences
And one of us is isConnected, to know if the user is connected, it's just a boolean

Comment: How many SharedPreferences do you have then?